# Get last active window in VBA

Tags: vba, window

This is not a duplicate question.

I have a `UserForm` which remains on top of all the windows all the time. I want to access source of an already open webpage. I can't use `findWindow` function as I will have multiple browser window open with the exact same title. I am left with only one option - Switch to the required browser window and as the `UserForm` is on top click some button to switch to the last active window. After that i'll be using `getForegroundWindow` function.

How can I Switch to the last active window without using `findWindow` or `SendKeys {"%Tab"}`(This doesn't work)? I have searched whole internet but couldn't get an answer.

Minimizing the form and getting the handle is working but while checking all open windows getting error on `For` loop line as `No more threads can be created in the system`

```
Function GetIEByHWND(myHWND As Long) As InternetExplorer
    Dim tempWindow As Variant
    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    Set GetIEByHWND = Nothing

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    For Each tempWindow In objShellWindows
        If InStr(tempWindow.Path, "INTERNET") Then
           If myHWND = tempWindow.hwnd Then
               Set GetIEByHWND = tempWindow
               Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next tempWindow

    Exit Function
```

Comment: `Last active window` do you mean the last active TAB? or different instances of browser with the same title?

Comment: Not the last active Tab. I don't have multiple tabs, I have multiple browser windows. I will open the `ie` window of which the `source` is needed but the problem is when i'll click `button` on the `UserForm` to capture the source of active window the focus will shift to the `UserForm` hence i have to shift the `focus` to the `last active window` again.Similar to `Alt + Tab`.

Comment: Ok I have two theories on how to go about it. They are untested though. `Theory 1` Enumerate through all open windows and check their Z order. Find the 2nd topmost window (1st will be your form) and then get it's handle. `Theory 2` Minimize your userform for couple of seconds using "ShowWindow" with "SW_MINIMIZE" and then get the handle of the active window.

Comment: I have deleted the comment see the code in the question.

Comment: No.. You don't do it like that... See this [LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183009)

Comment: If I have the handle to the required ie window, how can I set that window to an Internet explorer object without checking all the open windows?

Comment: Ok, how did you get the handle?

Comment: By using GetForegroundWindow 
`Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long`

Comment: But that would not give you the window that you are looking for. It will give you the topmost windows handle which is your userform.

Comment: I hope someone upvotes your post so that you have more than 20 points and then we can chat :)

Comment: That's what was my question was how to switch to last active window. Your solution of minimizing the form seems to work. When the userform is minimized the active window will be the required IE window i.e. the foregroundwindow. so the above function will give me handle of that window.

Comment: Oh Ok. So you are following `THEORY 2`? I was talking in terms of `Theory 1`.

Comment: Yes I am going by theory 2. Now that I have the handle i want to set that window to an internet explorer object.

Comment: Sorry got distracted on an another thread. Ok let me do some tests and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying? This is based on `THEORY 2`

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Const SW_MINIMIZE = 6
Const SW_RESTORE = 9

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Application.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim hwnd As Long, RetVal As Long

    hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
    RetVal = ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE)

    '~~> This is required so that GetForegroundWindow
    '~~> doesn't pick up the userforms handle
    Sleep 2000

    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow()

    If GetIEByHWND(hwnd) Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Not Able to get the object"
    Else
       MsgBox "Was able to get the object"
    End If

    RetVal = ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE)

    Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Function GetIEByHWND(myHWND As Long) As Object
    Dim tempWindow As Variant
    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    Set GetIEByHWND = Nothing

    For Each tempWindow In objShellWindows
        If InStr(1, tempWindow.Path, "INTERNET", vbTextCompare) Then
            If myHWND = tempWindow.hwnd Then
                Set GetIEByHWND = tempWindow
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next tempWindow
End Function
```

**FOLLOWUP**

See this code where I am interacting with the IE object.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim hwnd As Long, RetVal As Long
    Dim IE As Object

    hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)
    RetVal = ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE)

    '~~> This is required to that GetForegroundWindow
    '~~> doesn't pick up the userforms handle
    Sleep 2000

    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow()

    Set IE = GetIEByHWND(hwnd)

    If IE Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Not Able to get the object"
    Else
       MsgBox "Was able to get the object"

       IE.Visible = False '<~~ Interacting with IE

       Sleep 2000

       IE.Visible = True
    End If

    RetVal = ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE)

    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. I'm trying the same thing. Is there another way of doing this. Since we have the `handle` can we directly set the window as an `IE` object?

Comment: Let me amend the above code so that I can show you how to interact with the object.

Comment: Refresh the page and see FOLLOWUP :)

Comment: I'm using the same code but I'm getting error in GetIEByHWND method that's why I was asking for an alternative.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried the code before posting and just retried it again and it works. Did you copy the function as it is or did you make any changes to it?

Comment: I had the exact code already in my system. It was working yesterday. Now it has stopped working and it's giving error.

Comment: My function is slightly different than yours... And hence I am asking that did you use my function or your function?

Comment: I restarted my PC and my code is working now. Seems that there was some problem with the system. Anyways thanks for your solution. It really helped me a lot

Comment: Going by your `theory 2`, I'm able to get the handle of `last active foreground window`. This works fine if I have only one window open and no extra tabs. How can i get the `handle` if the `IE window` has `multiple tabs` open, I have to get the handle of `last active foreground child window`?

Comment: Again the title of the window is of no use as there will be multiple windows with the same title. I have to get the `handle` of `last active tab` only

Comment: @mayur2j: And hence my first comment under your question... That is the reason why I had asked you `do you mean the last active TAB? or different instances of browser with the same title?` The above code won't work for that scenario :) It's altogether a different and complex process.

Comment: Any solution for different tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error in GetIEbyHWND.

try putting a sleep in between

```
hwnd = GetForegroundWindow()
Sleep 2000
Set IE = GetIEByHWND(hwnd)
```

Or this solution

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Function oGetLatestIE(sURL As String, & _
Optional sWindowTitle As String = "MyWindowtitle") As Object

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Navigate sURL

Dim hwnd As Long

hwnd = GetForegroundWindow() ' get latest IE window
Set IE = Nothing  ' work around for windows 7 (intranet)

i = 0
Do While i < 10 And IE Is Nothing

    i = i + 1
    Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    For Each objWindow In objShellApp.Windows
        DoEvents

        If LCase(objWindow.LocationName) = LCase(sWindowTitle) Then

            If objWindow.hwnd = hwnd Then 'active IE window if more than one with same title
            Set IE = objWindow

            End If
        End If
    Next
    DoEvents
    sleep 100
Loop

If IE Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "nothing"
Exit Function
End If

Set oGetLatestIE = IE

End Function
```